# Python: Append dictionary in another file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, append

i am working on a program and I need to access a dicionary from another file, which I know how to do.I also need to be able to append the same dictionary and have it saved in its current form to the other file.

is there anyway to do this?

EDIT:

the program requires you to log in. you can create an account, and when you do it needs to save that username:password  you entered into the dictionary. The way I had it, you could create an account, but once you quit the program, the account was deleted.

Comment: What do you mean with "saved to the other file"? Does `dict1.update(**dict2)` not suffice? Do you actually want to serialize the dict and save it to file? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Ludo `dict1.update(**dict2)` is completely useless, inefficient, can cause stackoverflows with big enough dictionaries and relies on implementation details that might prevent it to work in the future. You *ought* to do simply `dict1.update(dict2)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Do you have a reference for that statement?

Comment: @Ludo In python3 you'll receive a `TypeError: keyword arguments must be strings` if the dictionary doesn't have string as keys rendering that method completely useless in many situations.

Comment: @Bakuriu That's new to me (but admittedly, I work mostly with Python 2.x). Also a bit surprising, and I don't directly understand why this design decision was made for Python 3

Comment: i created an account and updated the dict -->     dict1.update(dict2). with the username and password. But i had the same problem where when I close the program, and open it again and try the user/pass I created, it does not recognize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store and retrieve data structures using the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module in python, which provides object serialisation.

**Save the dictionary**

```
import pickle
some_dict = {'this':1,'is':2,'an':3,'example':4}

with open('saved_dict.pkl','w') as pickle_out:
    pickle.dump(some_dict,pickle_out)
```

**Load the dictionary**

```
with open('saved_dict.pkl.'r') as pickle_in:
    that_dict_again = pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

Comment: i tried this:                                                  self.accounts = pickle.load(open('logins.pkl','rb'))                       it gave me this error:                                      
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'logins.p'                                            i dont know why because it works in IDLE

Comment: Is the logins.pkl file in the correct place relative to the script you're running?

Comment: what do you mean? in the same folder?

Comment: Basically, yes - if you were opening`'picklefiles/logins.pkl'` it would be in a folder called `picklefiles` which would be located in the same folder as your script. It's a relative, rather than absolute path.